# PipeLine Shell in c when com,mend happen the shell close

Tags: c, shell, pipeline

I am implementing a pipeline in shell i.e: ls|sort

the shell has many commands like DIR, COPY, | - means pipeline, and so on...

When I run this command (ls|sort) its works

**The Problem is:** the shell exit and doesn't wait for the next commands in the shell after the command in the pipeline function.

I think because is something with the STDIN, STDOUT when I close them or something

Note that the pipeline only takes 2 commands.

Here is my code for the pipeline part:

```
    void Pipeline(char *input) {
    char delim[] = "|";
    char *token;
    char *vec[1024] = {0};
    int k = 0;
    for (token = strtok(input, delim); token; token = strtok(NULL, delim)) {
        vec[k++] = token;
    }
    vec[k] = NULL;
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    if(pipe(fd) == -1){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1){
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0){
        close(fd[0]); //close read from pipe, in parent
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); // Replace stdout with the write end of the pipe
        close(fd[1]); // Don't need another copy of the pipe write end hanging about
        execlp(vec[0], vec[0], NULL);
    }
    else{
        close(fd[1]); //close write to pipe, in child
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); // Replace stdin with the read end of the pipe
        close(fd[0]); // Don't need another copy of the pipe read end hanging about
        execlp(vec[1], vec[0], NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On success, exec-family functions such as `execlp()` *replace* the currently running program image with the requested one.  They return only on failure to do that.  Your function `fork`s once and performs an `execlp()` in both parent and child, thus, yes, if everything succeeds then the original program does not process any more input itself.  It no longer exists.

To avoid that, you need to fork a child for *each* command that requires an exec.  Also, for a pipeline with n > 2 commands, you will need n - 1 pipes for their communication.

Furthermore, you need to correctly handle the error case of `execlp()` returning (at all).  At minimum, a child process in which that happens should terminate quickly, probably by calling `_exit(1)`.  I would advise also emitting a diagnostic message, however, probably by use of `perror()`.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your answer. I Didn't understand what you mean by fork a child for each command you mean to make a for loop before pid = fork() with k-1 steps of all code?, and I change the exit lines to perror

Comment: @ATB, The key point here with respect to the question posed is that each call to `execlp()` should happen inside its own child process that was `fork()`ed from your shell.  Your present code handles only two-element pipelines, without looping over the `execlp()` calls, and I don't see why adding appropriate extra `fork()`ing would require adding any looping.  However, if you want to be able to support pipelines with an arbitrary number of segments then you'll need either to loop or to recurse, independent of the need to `fork()` for each `execlp()`.